# How to copy files inside a folder without other folders in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am having the following folder structure:

```
Folder1
  -Folder2
  -File1
  -File2
  -File3
```

I have tried the following in batch script to copy all inside the **Folder1**

```
echo d | xcopy "Folder1\*.*" "DestinationFolder"/f /s /y /r
```

But I need to copy only **File1, File2, File3**. Need to ignore **Folder2**. I don't have any idea about how to achieve this. Please help me resolve this.

Comment: You may only need to use the `Copy` command…`Copy /Y "Folder1\*.*" "DestinationFolder"`

Answer (score 0):

If Folder2 is empty, `/S` will do,
but since you have `/s` in your command, so I guess it's not empty.

So use this:

```
echo \Folder2\>__tmp4Exclude__
echo d | xcopy "Folder1\*.*" "DestinationFolder" /f /s /y /r /EXCLUDE:__tmp4Exclude__
del __tmp4Exclude__
```

`__tmp4Exclude__` is a temp file created to contain the list of files to exclude while copying.

From `xcopy /?`:

```
  /EXCLUDE:file1[+file2][+file3]...
               Specifies a list of files containing strings.  Each string
               should be in a separate line in the files.  When any of the
               strings match any part of the absolute path of the file to be
               copied, that file will be excluded from being copied.  For
               example, specifying a string like \obj\ or .obj will exclude
               all files underneath the directory obj or all files with the
               .obj extension respectively.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `xcopy` to copy **just** files! `xcpoy` is **usually** used to copy directory trees.

So, use `copy` instead. You can do:

```bat
copy "Folder1\*.*" "Destination\"
```

Probably you may need to use `/(-)Y` option:

> `/Y`        Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an  existing destination file.
>    `/-Y`        Causes prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file.

<sup><sup>From `copy /?` (`copy` help page)</sup></sup>